# CTest generate and submit gcov.tar to CDash after make <target>

Tags: cmake, branch, code-coverage, ctest, cdash

I have set up CDash on my local machine and I'm using CTest to upload testing results to CDash - generating .gcov-files containing Branch Coverage info and packing them into gcov.tar beforehand (this is a modified version of the example from https://blog.kitware.com/additional-coverage-features-in-cdash/):

**CMakeLists.txt:**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)
project(branch_coverage_example)

add_executable(foo foo.cxx)
include(CTest)
add_test(NAME foo COMMAND foo)

include(BranchCoverage)
```

**BranchCoverage.cmake** within my CMake modules path:

```
if(${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE} STREQUAL "Profiling")
    option(ALWAYS_GENERATE_BRANCH_COVERAGE_INFO "Run gcov branch coverage as part of the ALL target" ON)

    if(ALWAYS_GENERATE_BRANCH_COVERAGE_INFO)
        add_custom_target(BranchCoverage)

        add_custom_command(TARGET BranchCoverage
            POST_BUILD
            COMMAND ${CMAKE_CTEST_COMMAND} -D ExperimentalSubmit -S cdash_tarball.cmake
            WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}
            COMMENT "Generating gcov.tar containing branch coverage info..."
            )

        add_dependencies(BranchCoverage Experimental)
    endif()
endif()
```

**CTestConfig.cmake:**

```
## This file should be placed in the root directory of your project.
## Then modify the CMakeLists.txt file in the root directory of your
## project to incorporate the testing dashboard.
##
## # The following are required to submit to the CDash dashboard:
##   ENABLE_TESTING()
##   INCLUDE(CTest)

set(CTEST_PROJECT_NAME "BranchCoverageExample")
set(CTEST_NIGHTLY_START_TIME "01:00:00 UTC")

set(CTEST_DROP_METHOD "http")
set(CTEST_DROP_SITE "localhost")
set(CTEST_DROP_LOCATION "/CDash/public/submit.php?project=BranchCoverageExample")
set(CTEST_DROP_SITE_CDASH TRUE)
```

**cdash_upload.cmake:**

```
# start, configure, build, test, coverage and submit
# have been executed by make <target> beforehand!

# generate a GCOV tarball and upload it to CDash.
include(CTestCoverageCollectGCOV)
ctest_coverage_collect_gcov(
  TARBALL gcov.tar
  SOURCE ${CTEST_SOURCE_DIRECTORY}
  BUILD ${CTEST_BINARY_DIRECTORY}
  GCOV_COMMAND ${CTEST_COVERAGE_COMMAND}
  GCOV_OPTIONS -l -p -b
)
if(EXISTS "${CTEST_BINARY_DIRECTORY}/gcov.tar")
  ctest_submit(CDASH_UPLOAD "${CTEST_BINARY_DIRECTORY}/gcov.tar"
    CDASH_UPLOAD_TYPE GcovTar)
endif()
```

It works when I invoke the script from the example using ctest directly:

```
ctest -V -S run_example.cmake
```

This gives me wonderful branch coverage information in CDash. However this does not:

```
make Experimental
```

It ends up saying:

```
Generating gcov.tar containing branch coverage info...
CMake Error at /usr/local/share/cmake-3.6/Modules/CTestCoverageCollectGCOV.cmake:118 (file):
  file STRINGS file "/CMakeFiles/TargetDirectories.txt" cannot be read.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cdash_tarball.cmake:2 (ctest_coverage_collect_gcov)


ctest_coverage_collect_gcov: No .gcda files found, ignoring coverage request.
```

I guess this has something to do with the paths/env vars I need to give *cdash_upload.cmake*, when I do that using **-DCTEST_SOURCE_DIRECTORY** at *add_custom_command* in *BranchCoverage.cmake*, CDash returns a "Bad HTTP response", but doesn't give me any indication what I should fix and where.

Do you guys have any idea?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You are getting

```
file STRINGS file "/CMakeFiles/TargetDirectories.txt" cannot be read.
```

Because in this function call:

```
ctest_coverage_collect_gcov(
  TARBALL gcov.tar
  SOURCE ${CTEST_SOURCE_DIRECTORY}
  BUILD ${CTEST_BINARY_DIRECTORY}
  GCOV_COMMAND ${CTEST_COVERAGE_COMMAND}
  GCOV_OPTIONS -l -p -b
)
```

`CTEST_BINARY_DIRECTORY` is not defined,

it should be set to the build directory of your project,
and turns out it isn't otherwise you should get instead of

```
"/CMakeFiles/TargetDirectories.txt"
```

smth like:

```
"build/Debug/CMakeFiles/TargetDirectories.txt"
```

Once it is set everything should work fine.

You can look up how is used [here](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/blob/master/Modules/CTestCoverageCollectGCOV.cmake)